# Cropping head square

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, crop, opencv

I have images as shown below.

[image] [image]

And I want to crop only the head square as shown below.

[image] [image]

Is there any way I can achieve this? Either using Keras Data generator or just a normal python cropping function.
I tried below functionality but could not achieve the expected result.

```
def crop_center(pil_img, crop_width, crop_height):
img_width, img_height = pil_img.size
return pil_img.crop(((img_width - crop_width) // 2,
                     (img_height - crop_height) // 2,
                     (img_width + crop_width) // 2,
                     (img_height + crop_height) // 2))
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need Keras Data generator for cropping image.

You can use python packages such as `PIL` (pillow) or `cv2` (opencv) to crop the image.

> You need x,y coordinates of head box/square and crop width and height
> to do what you want.

You're using PIL crop in a wrong way.

**What you need to do is:**

```
cropped_image = pil_img.crop((x-top_left, y-top_left,x-bottom_right, y-bottom_right))
cropped_image.show()
```

**Note:**

```
x-bottom_right = x-top_left + crop_width
y-bottom_right = y-top_left + crop_height
```

**Additionally with OpenCV:**

```
import cv2
orig_img = cv2.imread("path_to_your_image")
crop_img = orig_img[y:y+h, x:x+w]
cv2.imshow("Cropped Image", crop_img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
```

Here x, y are x, y coordinates of **`head-box/square`** that you want to crop i.e `x-top_left` and `y-top_left` respectively.

```
w = crop_width
h = crop_height
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I want this operation for a whole dataset, so I can't specify the co-ordinates for all images separately (as these co-ordinates vary depending on the image). I want something where I can perform this crop for the complete dataset. Is there any way I can achieve this?

Comment: `cv2` and `pillow` will perform crop based on supplied co-ordinates only and they don't understand where head is present. Only way to do what you want is to use object detector i.e to be specific `head detector`. Basically you need to run head detector model on data set which gives predicted head box, which you can use to crop the image using the methods I specified. Note that wherever detection fails, you need to manually crop them. You can use pre-trained head detector models like this - https://github.com/pranoyr/head-detection-using-yolo additionally